# Prove that there is no continuous injective function from closed rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

Prove that there is no continuous function from a closed rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that is injective.

How can I start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose such a function $f:R:=I\times I\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ exists. Let $p\in R^\circ$. Then $f|_{R-\{p\}}$ too is a continuous function, and $R-\{p\}$ is connected. But its image is not (why?).

Comment: Thanks, but what do you mean by $R^\circ$?

Comment: @luka5z A point in the interior of the rectangle.

Comment: Ok, very nice argument. I'm really impressed! Continuous functions take connected sets to connected sets. In this case it would fail because image of $f|_{R-\{p\}}$ would have "a gap" (we use injection there).

Comment: Since the image of $f$ is a closed interval, it's just sufficient to take $p\in R$ such that $f(p)$ is not one of the extremes of the image.